# Number of Tasks in Spark UI

Tags: apache-spark, spark-ui

I am new to Spark. I have couple of questions regarding the Spark Web UI:-

- I have seen that Spark can create multiple **Jobs** for the same
  application. On what basis does it creates the **Jobs** ?
- I understand Spark creates multiple Stages for a single Job around
  Shuffle boundaries. Also I understand that there is `1` task per
  partition. However, I have seen that a particular Stage (E.g. Stage1)
  of a particular Job creating lesser number of tasks than the default
  shuffle partitions value (for e.g. only `2/2` completed). And I have
  also seen, the next    Stage (Stage 2) of the same Job creating
  `1500` tasks (for E.g. `1500/1500`    completed) which is more than
  the default shuffle partitions value.

  So, how does Spark determine how    many **tasks** should it
  create for any particular Stage to    execute ?

Can anyone please help me understand the above.

Answer (score 0):

the max number of task in one moment dependent on you cores and exec numbers,
different stage have different task number